# Magento 2 - setting a container class programatically

Tags: magento2, html, containers

How can I retrieve a container from the layout programmatically and then set/update the htmlClass?

I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
$container = $layout->getContainer('main.content');
$container->setAttribute('htmlClass', 'className');
```